# How to make button grayed out and non-clickable when value is 0 in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, numbers, onclicklistener

I need help with my reactjs button i dont want to use react-bootstrap but just mainly native react button. That will enable to perform the following criteria for me when its clicked.

// requirement for the button

-If the value is 0, - button should be grayed out and non-clickable.
-If the value is 3 and you press + value changes to 4.
-If an incorrect value is entered using input field(e.g -10),
on blur-event that value should change to last valid valued used instead

```
// buttons to decrease and increase 
 const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);  
 const incrementCount = () => {  
   // Update state with incremented value  
   setCounter(counter + 1);  
 };  
 const decrementCount = () => {  
   // Update state with incremented value  
   setCounter((c) => Math.max(c - 1, 0));  
 }; 

<div className="btn-group" role="group"> <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={decrementCount} > - -</button>  
    <input type="number" min="1" defaultValue={counter} className="form-control" />  
    <button  type="button"  className="btn btn-warning"  onClick={incrementCount} > + </button> 
      </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You already defined everything just add a `style` prop.

Comment: @Dennis Vash do you mind showing style or css for my button. The buttons are not clickable though i did test them and no error

Answer (score 0):

you can use `disabled={counter==0}` as a prop for `-` button and it will be disabled when counter is 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).